# Problems creating the index with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I appeal to you because I can no longer think how to do this.
I have the following schema, and I need to create the index of title and ndoc, but for some reason only I create the title leaving it as `title_text`, being the case I need `title_text` and `ndoc_text`.

```
var favoritoSchema = Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    url: { type: String },
    ndoc: {type: Number }
});

favoritoSchema.index({ title: "text", ndoc: "text" });

favoritoSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {inc_field: 'ndoc',collection_name: "favorito_counters"});
```

In the backend I am occupying node, mongoose and mongoDB.
I hope I have explained well and appreciate who can help me to resolve this.

Comment: please, be a bit more clear in the explanation. "but for some reason only I..." is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that when I use this code it works, but I can only search in `title`, and I need the search engine to work with `title` and `ndoc`

`favoritoSchema.index({ title: "text" });`

Comment: You know you don't need to index the things to make the search, right? You can do favoritoSchema.find({ndoc:10}).exec(function) out of the box

Comment: What is `ndoc` for ?